# Viewing my iphone 5s pics on icloud on my computer

Tags: icloud

How do I view my pics from my iphone cloud on my computer

Comment: What kind of computer do you have (Mac or PC)? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

Photo Stream photos are stored in the following location providing you have either iPhoto or Aperture installed and have signed in with your Apple ID.

```
~/Library/Application Support/iLifeAssetManagement/assets/sub
```